# Android AlertDialog.Builder method getContext() not defined

Tags: android, dialog, undefined

The reference page for AlertDialog.Builder has a [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#getContext%28%29) method listed for API 11+, but this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(builder.getContext());
}
```

will display an error in Eclipse:

```
 The method getContext() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder
```

But I'm using API level 15 so I would have thought it were available. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Comment: What is the minimum version in your manifest?

Comment: I had min version 8, just tried 11 and 15 but it didn't seem to fix the error

Comment: Also keep in mind that since you're calling from `onCreate()`, getContext() will return the same Activity instance. Edit: Try cleaning your project now.

Comment: hiya, cleaning it also didn't help but it did make me suddenly remember that the build target was set for the minimum API, and putting the target up to 4.0 fixed the problem. Woops. Thanks though!